# Firefox extension: open download link in download window

Tags: firefox-addon, window, download-manager

I have an extension which opens links via context menu just like built-in `Open link in new tab` Firefox menu (just below it; My context menu item is `Download link`).

When a user select this option from link context menu a new tab is opened by Firefox and then the download is started in `download manager` window.
After a while, this will end-up many blank tabs opened when the user right click on links and use my extension (he should close them manually).

I have tried `Javascript` command `window.open` but it will open a new window which is worse than opening a new tab!

How can I prevent opening a new tab each time and start the download directly in Firefox `download manager` window ?

OR

How can I close that tab/window when the page content is a download?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the [nsIDownloadManger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDownloadManager) interface to directly add downloads to the download manager. To automatically start downloading after you also need a [nsIWebBrowserPersist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWebBrowserPersist) object.